# Unable to receive push messages

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

When i push any message i get com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION ungeristered in extras and not getting com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE as action.I am using Azure Mobile Engagement SDK.It works fine for Android 4.2 devices and above but the issue is being encountered in prior devices.Below is my Manifest file for refference.My package name is "com.my.package"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<permission android:name="com.my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<application
    android:name="com.my.package.MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value="com.my.package.activity.SearchableActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SearchableActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SearchableMoreActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.HomeActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.my.package.OrangeApp.activity.HOMEACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SettingsActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ContentDetailsActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:launchMode="standard"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.EventContentActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:launchMode="standard"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MyAccountActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.InfoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ShareActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.HelpActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ArtistItemDetailsActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:launchMode="standard"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MusicEventActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:launchMode="standard"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>

   <service
        android:name="com.microsoft.azure.engagement.service.EngagementService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="OrangeService"
        android:process=":Engagement" />

   <activity android:name="com.my.package.engagementActivity.EngagementTextAnnouncementActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.microsoft.azure.engagement.reach.intent.action.ANNOUNCEMENT"/>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     <activity android:name="com.my.package.engagementActivity.EngagementWebAnnouncementActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.microsoft.azure.engagement.reach.intent.action.ANNOUNCEMENT"/>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             <data android:mimeType="text/html" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     <activity android:name="com.microsoft.azure.engagement.reach.activity.EngagementPollActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.microsoft.azure.engagement.reach.intent.action.POLL"/>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>

     <activity android:name="com.microsoft.azure.engagement.reach.activity.EngagementLoadingActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.microsoft.azure.engagement.reach.intent.action.LOADING"/>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     <receiver android:name="com.microsoft.azure.engagement.reach.EngagementReachReceiver" android:exported="false">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
             <action android:name="com.microsoft.azure.engagement.intent.action.AGENT_CREATED"/>
             <action android:name="com.microsoft.azure.engagement.intent.action.MESSAGE"/>
             <action android:name="com.microsoft.azure.engagement.reach.intent.action.ACTION_NOTIFICATION"/>
             <action android:name="com.microsoft.azure.engagement.reach.intent.action.EXIT_NOTIFICATION"/>
             <action android:name="com.microsoft.azure.engagement.reach.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT"/>
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
     <receiver android:name="com.microsoft.azure.engagement.reach.EngagementReachDownloadReceiver">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>


     <meta-data android:name="engagement:reach:notification:icon" android:value="ic_launcher"/>
     <meta-data android:name="engagement:gcm:sender" android:value="xxxxxxxxx\n" />

     <receiver android:name="com.my.package.engagementActivity.MyGCMEnabler" android:exported="false">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.microsoft.azure.engagement.intent.action.APPID_GOT" />
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".MyGCMReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.my.package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>
```

Comment: Have a look through this sample project, it shows how to use Gcm in android https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm

Comment: Can you post code of what you have tried?

Comment: That's a lot of XML. How about a [mcve]?

Comment: I have tried registering first which happens successfully.The MyGCMReceiver is my broadcast receiver. The onReceive method of it gets the control where i get action as com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION and registration_id in extras.

Comment: Now when i send a push message,the OnReceive method of MyGCMReceiver gets invoked,but instead of getting com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE as the action i am getting com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION again and the extras value has unregistered as key.

Comment: Few of the similar post suggested that the problem lies in the Manifest file ,that is the reason i posted the same here,incase anyone can identify whats going wrong here

Comment: You have a single receiver for registration and messages?

Comment: Yes and that Reciever i declared in Manifest

Comment: <receiver android:name=".MyGCMReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.my.package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

Comment: Once i receive message i send the intent to another Broadcast receiver which handles the generating of Notifications

Comment: Seems there is no one who ran into this scenario yet.Strange

Comment: Can anyone identify whats going wrong with my Manifest file permission etc?

Comment: Anyone having thorough understanding of GCM architecture please help me with the above issue